# What is Autodesk Revit's backend database structure?

Tags: revit-api, revit

Autodesk Revit has the ability to export to a relational database structure through its existing toolset.

But, for Revit itself, is it structured with a non-relational database, as the API has each project being represented as a 'Document'?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know and I do not care, since the only way to interact programmatically with the Revit database and its elements and properties is via the Revit API.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say exactly what the Database behind Revit is but I can say some of its configs are on XML format (some are in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Revit Shared\Ashrae for Mechanical and so on) and so many other Databases .and you can't say exactly it's relational or non-relational.

Comment: I understand that there are probably not many people that can answer the question, but thanks for the feedback.